# JavaScript & HTML: onclick button to run javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, socket.io, electron

I am setting up a GUI server application using electron and socket.io. I cannot get the onclick button in `index.html` to run the `startServer()` function in `server.js`. I need assistance please

I've tried to use an ID and event listeners to run the function. Help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

main.js:

```
const electron = require('electron')
const app = electron.app
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow

const path = require('path')

let mainWindow

function createWindow() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    height: 500,
    width: 700,
    frame: false,
    resizable: false,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  });

  // Load html into window
  mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/app/index.html');

  mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
    mainWindow = null
  })
}

// Listen for app to be ready
app.on('ready', createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
</head>
<body>
  <script>server.js</script>
  <div class="disable-highlight">
    <h1>DNPS
    </h1>
  </div>
  <input type="button" onclick="startServer()" value="Start Server" />
  <script>
    require('./server.js')
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

server.js:

```
const log = require('electron-log')

function startServer() {
  // Load Socket.io
  var app = require('express')();
  var http = require('http').createServer(app);
  var io = require('socket.io')(http);

  app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('<h1>Hello world</h1>');
  });

  io.on('connection', function(socket){
    log.info('a user connected')
  });

  http.listen(3000, function(){
    log.info('listening on *:3000');
  });
};
```

Comment: Your file `server.js` doesn't have the correct structure of a node module. And you don't use it correctly either. Look at a tutorial on how to write and use modules in javascipt

Comment: There is a node module of `main.js`. If I start `main.js` then `server.js` starts no problem if I remove the outlying `function startServer() {...}` but I need the `function startServer() {...}` so I can call the function using a button in html but it won't let me.

Comment: It's as if `socket.io` must start when the script is loaded and not called in a function but I don't see why it can't be?

Answer (score 0):

after much fiddling I have found that `document.getElementById` worked for me.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="disable-highlight">
    <h1>DNPS</h1>
  <input id="startBtn" type="button" value="Start Server"/>
  <script>require('./server.js')</script>
  <table class='center'>
    <td id="consoleLog">
    </td>
  </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

server.js:

```
const log = require('electron-log')

// Load Socket.io
const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

var tempLog = ''

function pushLog() {
  document.getElementById('consoleLog').innerHTML = tempLog
}

document.getElementById('startBtn').onclick = function() {
  app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/output/index.html');
  });

  log.info('pushing index.html to localhost')
  tempLog += 'pushing index.html to localhost<br>'

  io.on('connection', function(socket){
    tempLog += 'a user connected<br>'
    log.info('a user connected<br>')
    pushLog()
  });

  http.listen(3000, function(){
    tempLog += 'listening on *:3000<br>'
    log.info('listening on *:3000');
    pushLog()
  });
};
```